# Parse date with unicode token format string with wildcard separator characters

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, date-fns

I'm using [date-fns 2 (alpha)](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.23/docs/parse) to parse a date string into a JavaScript Date. This version of the library uses [unicode tokens](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) for the format/parse strings.

I would like to be able to parse a date string whilst not caring particularly about the separator characters.

E.g. say I want to parse the following date: "18/11/2018". I can use the format `dd/MM/yyyy`. Which works great:

```
> dateFns.parse('18/11/2018', 'dd/MM/yyyy', new Date());
2018-11-18T00:00:00.000Z
```

But say I want to parse a date formatted as "18 11 2018" the original format string will fail:

```
> dateFns.parse('18 11 2018', 'dd/MM/yyyy', new Date());
Invalid Date
```

Given the separator character has no impact the value of the date itself, is there a way to construct a format string that essentially ignores it?

Comment: You could use a RegEx on the input to replace them with `/`, eg. -> `"18 11 2018".replace(/(\d*).(\d*).(\d*)/, "$1/$2/$3")`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert a date string in `dd mm yyyy` format with a variety of separators to a js date object (in UTC), you could use regex to parse the strings and then `new Date(Date.UTC(...))`. For example:

```js
const convertDate = (dstring) => {
  const [d, m, y] = dstring.match(/\d+/g);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(y, m - 1, d));
};

// the below demonstrates output for a variety of date string separators
const dstrings = ['18/11/2018', '18 11 2018', '18-11-2018', '18.11.2018'];
for (const dstring of dstrings) {
  const date = convertDate(dstring);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(date));
}
```

Comment: Is this hairy hack the only way to address "wildcard" cases ? Isn't there sth more nice like '?' to indicate single whatever character to skip or '?{1-4}' to skip between 1 and 4 positions ?

Comment: @zaggi - there are a variety of messy ways to parse strings like this, and most of them depend on what you know about the input strings (leading / trailing characters and spaces, types of separators, separator length, etc). Tailoring your particular approach to what you know about the input strings is one way to handle this. Where possible, the better way is to fix the input data so you can avoid parsing altogether.